# Using Route::is() to check if the route is the homepage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can i check to see if the current route is the root page?

i've tried in a blade file typing thie following:

```
@if(Route::is('/')
//show something
@else 
//show something else
@endif
```

i've also tried it with Route::currentRouteName() such as

```
@if(Route::currentRouteName() == '/')
//do something
@else
//do something else
@endif
```

and it doesn't seem to work on the root page.
is there an alternative way? or is it that the root doesn't have a route?

Comment: what do you mean by root ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@if(Request::is('/'))
  //do something
@else
  //do something
@endif
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('root');

@if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'root')
  //do something
@else
 //do something else
@endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can also use `routeIs()`:

```
@if(request()->routeIs('home'))
  // yay
@else
  // nay
@endif
```

The helper works like the normal "is", which means that it supports multiple patterns, but matches against route names instead.

Answer (score 3):

you can use your function to check currentRouteName, you just need to make sure you set the name for that route like I mentioned below:

> Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

```
@if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'home')
//do something
@else
//do something else
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'route name here') // route name in web.php
```

or

```
if(Request::is('url in here'))  // page url
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@if(request()->routeIs('data'))
```

Comment: Why "`data`"? Is that the homepage? Based on the other answers, it doesn't look like it.